# Please explain class methods

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4

I'm finding it difficult to understand when it is necessary to create class methods. From what I've read, they are important for creating new objects, but I do not see how. The following class create a simple shape black rectangle. Can anyone show me how to incorporate a class method to do something that I could not do with an instance method?

Shape.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface Shape : UIView; 
- (id) initWithX: (int)xVal andY: (int)yVal;
@end
```

Shape.m

```
#import "Shape.h"
@implementation Shape 
- (id) initWithX:(int )xVal andY:(int)yVal {
self = [super init];    
UIView *shape = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xVal, yVal, 10, 10)];
shape.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self addSubview:shape];
return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: Did you notice that `alloc` is a class method? It must be since there's no object when it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class methods have several uses:

- As you've heard, they're essential for creating new objects. Creating objects is a two step process: first, you allocate memory for the object using the `+alloc` **class** method, then you initialize the object using some **instance** method that usually begins with `-init`. The `+alloc` method must be a class method because you don't have an instance upon which to call it; you only know the class name. The `-init` method should be an instance method, because `+alloc` returns an instance, an you want to initialize the properties unique to that instance, not to the entire class. So, you used a class method then an instance method in your code above:
  `UIView *shape = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xVal, yVal, 10, 10)];`
- Class methods are useful for retrieving singletons, or shared instances of a class. For example, the `NSUserDefaults` class stores preferences and settings associated with your app. In most cases, people like to use a single set of preferences for their entire app, so it has a class method `+standardUserDefaults` that returns a single instance of `NSUserDefaults`that everyone can use at any point in the app's lifetime to get all the preferences associated with an app. Without that singleton and class method, you'd have to create and pass around an instance of `NSUserDefaults` throughout your app, which gets messy. Other examples include `+[UIDevice currentDevice]` and `+[NSFileManager defaultManager]`.
- Class methods are great for returning data or properties shared by all instances of the class. For example, `UIView` has a class method `+layerClass` that returns the kind of layer the view hosts. Since all instances of a particular `UIView` subclass use the same kind of layer, it has nothing to do with individual instances and thus makes sense as a class method.
- You'll see a lot of class methods called "convenience methods." These methods (generally) combine calls to `+alloc` and `-init` and return an autoreleased instance of a class. For example, you can save some typing by writing `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]` instead of `[[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...] autorelease]`. If you're using ARC, these convenience methods are less useful, but they are still everywhere in Cocoa.
- Class methods are also sometimes used for utility classes, or classes that don't have state, and just have a bunch of methods that take in all the parameters they need. For example, you might have a method like `+[PhoneUtilities parseAreaCodeFromPhoneNumber:string]`.  There are not many of these methods built-in to Cocoa; some people argue that it's better to make them regular C functions, singletons, or regular objective-c classes with instance methods.

I'm sure there are more, but that should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Class methods:

- Can be called when you don't have an instance (yet)
- Aren't operating on an instance (unless one is passed in as a parameter or created by the method) and so don't have access to any particular instance's instance variables.
- Can be overridden in subclasses, unlike a simple function (which otherwise matches the previous points)

As pointed out by the others, I'm sure you use class methods all the time. If nothing else, then `+alloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Class methods are simply methods that don't need objects. Therefore, any instance method that doesn't use its object could be a class method. The only time you must use a class method is when a method must be called without an object. `alloc` is a good example: it creates the object and returns it, so by definition there is no object when it is called.

One other use I've had for class methods (in C++ in embedded systems, so I don't have code to show) is to have a class keep a doubly-linked list of all its objects. (This is useful for debugging dumps; in embedded development your debugging tools are often just some kind of `printf`.)

The class has two members which are pointers to the first and last elements of the list, and the constructor and destructor insert and remove an object from the list. The functions to access the first and last objects are class methods, since you call those when you want to traverse the list of objects but don't have an object yet.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be that class methods are very useful when you need to do some utility functions / methods and *don't* need to be doing actions on some specific instance or object.

For example, in my own code, I typically do class methods in classes where the outcome will be the same no matter which object I could possibly call the method on.  Like:

E.G.

```
@interface MyAppCacheFiles
    + (NSURL *) getFileURLOfLocalCache;
@end
```

These could also be considered convenience methods (e.g. much like `NSString +stringWithFormat:` or `NSArray +arrayWithArray:`).